# Windows 10 / MS-Word / missing list of recently edited files under Start Menu / right-click

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, start-menu, recent-items

I have MS-Office apps "pinned" to my Start menu.  MS-Word *used* to show the list of recently opened files when I right-clicked on the Word icon.  Now it doesn't.  How do I get it back??

- [image]

Excel still does show the list of recent files when I right-click.

- [image]

Both programs show the list of recent files from within the app

Comment: You're sure you didn't right-click Word in the Start Menu and selected "Clear recent items list"?

Comment: @harrymc: Yes I did that many weeks ago. Since then I have created, opened, saved and printed dozens of other files in Word.

Comment: A long shot: Open in Explorer the folder `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations` and check if there are files or folders named either `5f7b5f1e01b83767.automaticDestinations-ms` or `fb3b0dbfee58fac8.automaticDestinations-ms`.